# Can Cancan be used to restrict access to specific values for a single model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a Rails 3 application that has Categories.  A category can be administered by somebody with the Category Owner role.  But the Category Owner should only be able to access Categories that he owns, not others. I can lock down the admin functions using CanCan, but I need to restrict the specific categories themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in one of two ways.

You can either specify a hash of attributes to restrict access in your `Ability` class.

```
can :manage, Category, :user_id => user.id
```

Or you can use a block:

```
can :manage, Category do |c|
  c && c.user_id == user.id
end
```

These both check whether the `user_id` attribute on the category you are checking against matches the user you are checking for.

These are described under [Defining Abilities with Hashes](http://wiki.github.com/ryanb/cancan/defining-abilities-with-hashes) and [Defining Abilities with Blocks](http://wiki.github.com/ryanb/cancan/defining-abilities-with-blocks) respectively in the CanCan documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm so buried in Rails 3 I guess I didn't RTFM the CanCan docs!